# Display code if title of the custom post matches title of other post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-field

I have two custom posts, one called "reviews" and another called "guides".
I want to display a custom field from the post reviews if the title of the two matches.

Something like this: (I am not good with codes, this was the way I found to explain how I think it should be)

```
<? php
if ('$post_title' 'guides' == '$post_title' 'reviews') {
 echo ('custom_field' 'reviews');
 else
 return __(no details);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention exactly if you are referring to the default Custom Fields. If so, the solution bellow doesn't apply.

But, much better than the default, is to create a Custom Meta Box where you present your Custom Field(s).

The Codex has an example in [Function_Reference/add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).
These can also be useful:

- [add meta box - custom field : which to choose?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/18321/12615)
- [How to add option box in "Edit Post" plugin API?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/18290/12615)

*Check the comments in the code and also the message that's printed in the MB.*

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_box_wpse_75963' );

function add_meta_box_wpse_75963() 
{
    // This prevents the code from going further if not in the correct post type
    global $post;
    if( 'reviews' != $post->post_type )
        return;

    // Check if the other post type has a post with the same title
    // If it doesn't, bail out
    $other_page = get_page_by_title( $post->post_title, OBJECT, 'guides' );
    if( !$other_page )
        return;

    // We are in the correct post_type (reviews)
    // and there is another post in "guides" with the same title
    add_meta_box(
        'wpse_42440_sectionid',
        __( 'Custom Field' ), 
        'display_meta_box_wpse_75963',
        'reviews'
    );
}

function display_meta_box_wpse_75963() 
{ 
    echo "Insert custom field procedures here.";
    echo "Also create the appropriate <code>add_action( 'save_post', 'callback');</code>";
}
```